# Choosing Collectd time format

Tags: time, formatting, time-format, collectd

I'm pushing collectd stats to a fluentd instance via an http socket. The latter is complaining that the time format from collectd is a float not an integer. Here's an example output from collectd:

```
[{...,"time":1473707444.605,"interval":1.000,...]
```

As you can see, I'm outputting in `JSON` format.

I cannot modify this field in fluentd as it fails the message instantly*. So I have to specify a different time format in collectd. I like iso-8601 if at all possible.

Anyone know how to do that? I've trawled all the docs I can find but so far nothing :( I can't believe this is not specifiable.

*Edit: I was wrong about Fluentd not allowing time formatting. It does. However, my original question still stands as I think time formatting output should be possible somehow, no?

Answer (score 0):

Collectd does not allow changing the format of the time output that is sends.

Answer (score 0):

So I came across this issue while trying to store the "time" value in my backend database (influxdb). Although collectd does not allow changing the format, maybe an alternate is to do the conversion before sending it?

For example, I use ruby to parse the collectd time into a DateTime format before pushing it into the database

```
require 'date'

DateTime.strptime(collectdJsonStats.time.to_s,'%s')
```

where the *'collectdJsonStats'* is the json blob that you are tring to send.